# Git configuration repository, I push the changes in my new account it updates, but under the name of my old account

Tags: linux, git, github, configuration, branch

I have the following problem/issue with Git/Github:
I have 2 accounts MainAccount and NewAccount, I created a repository in NewAccount I was working on a project, but when I push all my changes it appears in my NewAccount, but it is under the name of my MainAccount I do not know why ??

So I do not know how to set up or what is the problem so the contribution and updates are reflected on my NewAccount under its name and not under my MainAccount name, the following image is the contribution panel on Github of my NewAccount:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because your local git settings are set to use the same name. For eg did you change git config to use a different name/email? If not, it would use whatever you have set in your global git config settings.

Follow these directions to update them again to use a different name https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup

Comment: Thank you, it was very useful, I found the reason, it was cuz I forgot to config my email con:

   git config --global user.email myEmail@email.com

Estaba con el email de mi MainAccount, por eso subía los cambios, pero como si lo hubiera subido con dicha cuenta.
It was with the email of my MainAccount that is the reason it was updating the changes, but under the name of my MainAccount just cuz the email.

Thanks!

Comment: @JuanJ, happy to help!